# How can I get the dynamic Id of nested form?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I got the following code, which I want to show the Add option button when the user chooses the OPTIONS type in the select box. It only works for the first time to add the question. I know the problem which is I gave the id to the select box, but if I do not do that, how can I get the dynamic id of the select box?

```html
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |question_form| %>

        <%= question_form.text_field :question_text %>
        <%= question_form.select(:question_type, [ 'TEXT', 'OPTIONS', 'UPLOAD' ],{:prompt => 'Select One'},  :id => "my_id", :onchange => "myFunction()") %>
        <%= question_form.link_to_remove "Remove this Question" %>
        <%= question_form.fields_for :options do |option_form| %>
            <%= option_form.text_field :option_text %>
            <%= option_form.link_to_remove "Remove this option" %>
        <% end %>
        <p id = "test" hidden><%= question_form.link_to_add "Add a option", :options %></p>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a Question", :questions %></p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    var e = document.getElementById("my_id");
    var x = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
    if (x == "OPTIONS"){
            document.getElementById("test").hidden = false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("test").hidden = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "It only works for the first time to add the question", it sounds like you're confident that using `document.getElementById()` is the problem. (I don't know why it would be, but I'm unfamiliar with Rails, so I'll assume you're correct.)

If so, you can avoid that selector by using the `target` property of the EventListeners's built-in "event" parameter:

```
function myFunction(event){
`var x = event.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value`
...
```

(And you might be able to shorten this to `event.target.value`.)

Comment: I want to implement a page which can let people add several questions dynamically.  In my code, If people add more then one questions, the function only works for the first question, because of all the select box have the same id. If I don't set the id to the select box, it will get a dynamic id which likes 'survey_questions_attributes_1551055147680_question_type', the number in the id which is different for each select box. So I want to know the method to get this dynamic id

Comment: Ok, then my suggestion above should fix it. (Or alternatively, you could declare a global counter variable that gets incremented and appended to 'my_id' for each new question, making `my_id1`, `my_id2`, etc -- but this seems unnecessarily complicated compared to just asking the `onchange` event which option the user selected.)